# Small == Equal while creating simple python code

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python so all of this is a bit new for me.

I'm trying to create a script in which it by itself thinks of a number and after wards wants the user to guess a number and enter it. It seemed to work but there are wo problems here.

It understands everything however it does not understand the == part.
Because even though the both numbers are the same, it still goes on towards the else statement.

```
import random

while True:


    Thethinker = random.randint(1,10)

    Guessnumber = (input("Guess a random number  "))

    if Guessnumber == Thethinker:
        print("Correct")
        print(Thethinker)
    else:
        print("Not correct")
        print(Thethinker)
```

Any help?

Comment: The two elements are not the same ... Thethinker is an `int`, Guessnumber is a `str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input returns a string instead of an integer. To get an integer do:

```
int(Guessnumber)
```

This is better than using str() because then if you ever want to change the numbers, you wouldn't be able to do that without doing the method I suggested

As far as I know, I don't do much Python

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Python 3, `input` returns a **string**.

In Python, a string and a number can never be "equal"; you have to transform one or the other.  E.g, if you use

```
Thethinker = str(random.randint(1,10))
```

**then** the equality-comparison with another string **can** succeed.